# How can I get the value of a fieldset legend and pass that value into a hidden field

Tags: jquery, variables, hidden-field, legend

I need a way to add a hidden field in a fieldset that holds the value of that fieldset's legend.

I'm able to get the input field added after each fieldset legend, but I can't get the value of the fieldset passed into the value of the hidden field.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var theLegend = $('legend');  
    $('<input type="hidden"name="hiddenList[]" value="' + theLegend.val() + '">').insertAfter('legend');
</script>
```

Overall what I'm trying to achieve is get the value of the fieldset legend to pass into the database.  I need the hidden fields to be within their respective fieldsets.  The forms are being built with a form builder within a CMS, and I cannot "hack" the code for the form builder, so I need a way to do this with jquery/javascript, and I'm pretty much a jquery newbie...

Comment: I think you are over thinking this, could you give us more code and perhaps provide a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net).  You appear to be trying to hard to do something that sounds extremely simply.

Comment: val() is used to get values from inputs.. You should use .text() to get the text inside the legend element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest something like the following:

```
$('legend').each(
    function(i,e){
        var that = $(e),
            parent = that.closest('fieldset'),
            text = that.text();
        $('<input />', {'type' : 'hidden', 'name' : 'hiddenList[]', 'value' : text})
            .appendTo(parent);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gM3ps/).

To see the output, right-click and 'inspect element' on the `legend` text.

One of the problems you were having is that you were using `val()` to retrieve the *text* of an element (only `input`, and `textarea` elements have a `value`/`val()`), whereas `text()` is what you want in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have your legend selected, use the .text() method instead of .val()

`theLegend.text()`